# Don't want div's background image appears thru table

Tags: jquery, html, css

say i have following code

```
<div class='mydiv'>
   <table class='mytable'>
      ....
   </table>

</div>
```

in css, i set

```
.mydiv {
   background-image: someurl
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;    
}
```

For my table, I set alternate color for even rows.

```
$(".mytable tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
```

In css, I have

```
.even {background-color: #EDEDED;}
```

Now what happens is that I can still still see the background image in odd rows,which is in white color by default. What can i do to completely hid the div background image? I only want to show the background image when the table is empty.

Comment: Why not add a solid background color to the odd rows?

Comment: ^then set the odd rows to white.

Comment: The background color of your odd rows is transparent by default. You must explicitly set it to white if that's the color you need.

Comment: I thought of that. Since some cells in the table contains subtable, for some reason this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your css a selector for rows that do not have the even class:

```
.mytable tr {
    background-color: white;
}
```

This **must** appear before the *.even* rule, so that cascading rules will cause that to take precedence. If there are no rows at all (empty table), the div background image should show.